# pypi see older versions of package

Tags: python, django, pypi

This is the package I'm interested in:

*[Django filebrowser no Grappelli](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-filebrowser-no-grappelli/)*

However, the latest version no longer supports Django 1.3. I need to find a version that does.
How do I see a list of older versions?

Comment: There seems to be no older packages available, that package alone is 2 years old

Comment: You really should consider upgrading your Django version. 1.3 has been unsupported for ages.

Comment: Grappelli 2.3.9 requires Django 1.3 . source:http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.9/

Comment: The question title is generic.  Others coming here might want to solve a similar issue for different libraries of different ages.

Comment: What is the title? A (literal) error message? Or something else?

Answer (score 85):

It's perhaps a little inelegant, but it appears that you can go to the URL

```
https://pypi.python.org/simple/<package>
```

And you will get a bunch of links to tarballs for the package.

Ex:

```
https://pypi.python.org/simple/django-filebrowser-no-grappelli/
```

Comment: This Works.. But PYPI should ideally add a link to access older packages too.

Comment: it is a elegant idea, though

Comment: @tan It's inelegant because you're bypassing the normal graphical interface and, *as a human*, requesting a page intended to be consumed by code (e.g. `pip` might use this page).

Answer (score 39):

This is visible in the new UI for pypi:

```
https://pypi.org/project/<package>/#history
```

For example:

```
https://pypi.org/project/django-filebrowser-no-grappelli/#history
```

Comment: This new UI is really nice and useful.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

You can use this short Python 3 script to grab the list of available versions for a package from PyPI using [JSON API](https://warehouse.readthedocs.io/api-reference/json/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys    
import requests
from pkg_resources import parse_version    

def versions(pkg_name):
    url = f'https://pypi.python.org/pypi/{pkg_name}/json'
    releases = requests.get(url).json()['releases']
    return sorted(releases, key=parse_version, reverse=True)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(*versions(sys.argv[1]), sep='\n')
```

Demo:

```
$ python versions.py django-filebrowser-no-grappelli
3.7.8
3.7.7
3.7.6
3.7.5
3.7.4
3.7.3
3.7.2
3.7.1
3.7.0
3.6.2
3.6.1
3.5.8
3.5.7
3.5.6
3.1.1
```

Comment: What does the domain `warehouse.readthedocs.io` represent?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It's the documentation for [Warehouse](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse) (the software that powers [PyPI](https://pypi.org/)).

Answer (score 8):

Using `pip` you can find out all the available versions of that package:

```
pip install django-filebrowser-no-grappelli==randomwords
```

This will produce an output of all the available packages:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
  django-filebrowser-no-grappelli==randomwords
(from versions: 3.1.1, 3.5.6, 3.5.7, 3.5.8, 3.6.1, 3.6.2, 3.7.0, 3.7.1, 3.7.2)
   No matching distribution found for
   django-filebrowser-no-grappelli==randomwords
```

Comment: This is the best by now for me, raised bounty for this. However, I still see it as a workaround, `pip` should have a clear option to list all available versions.

Answer (score 4):

Store the following code in the **get_version.py** file:

```
import json
import sys
import urllib2

from distutils.version import LooseVersion

name = sys.argv[1]

resp = urllib2.urlopen("https://pypi.python.org/pypi/{}/json".format(name))
data = json.load(resp)

for ver in sorted([LooseVersion(version) for version in data["releases"].keys()]):
    print ver.vstring
```

Run it to get a sorted list of all package versions:

```
python get_version.py %PACKAGE-NAME%
```

Comment: Where is the *get_version.py* file located?

Comment: What do you mean? You have to create the file and put the code outlined in my answer there.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `pip` to install your package, then you may use:

```
pip install yolk
yolk -V django-filebrowser-no-grappelli
```

Unfortunately the only available version seems to be:

```
django-filebrowser-no-grappelli 3.1.1
```

However, you can try to find another version on the Internet and install by:

```
pip install -Iv <url_package>
```