# Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I am going over Sweigart's *Automate the Boring Stuff with Python* text. I'm using [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE) and already installed the Selenium module and the Firefox browser.

Whenever I tried to run the webdriver function, I get this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Exception:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x00000249C0DA1080>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 163, in __del__
    self.stop()
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 135, in stop
    if self.process is None:
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x00000249C0E08128>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 163, in __del__
    self.stop()
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 135, in stop
    if self.process is None:
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 64, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I think I need to set the path for `geckodriver`, but I am not sure how, so how would I do this?

Comment: Please, see my answer on similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40186299/3022982)

Comment: I'm putting the geckodriver.exe in the Python/Python35 directory so it has the same path and I'm getting even more problems.

Comment: On Mac: `brew install geckodriver`

Comment: I found that running it through the Chrome browser is a little faster than on Firefox, you'll just have to download the `chromedriver` for this.

Comment: Note: there's [Testcafe](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/getting-started/) that got open-sourced recently. It doesn't require any browser plugins, they're built-in. I wanted to use Selenium but that looks like an interesting alternative.

Comment: [Check out following link for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048940/geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Comment: On Ubuntu follow these steps : https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-selenium-tools-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: any windows answer please? 90% are linux answer

Comment: @greendino [Very good multi language answer here](/a/38676858), also relevant depending on the chosen solution is [Adding a directory to the PATH environment variable in Windows](/q/9546324)

Comment: You can also specify the path to the `geckodriver` executable via `Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Service.driver_path = "path/to/geckodriver"`.

Answer (score 461, accepted):

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

[First of all you will need to download latest executable geckodriver from here to run latest Firefox using Selenium](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Actually, the Selenium client bindings tries to locate the `geckodriver` executable from the system `PATH`. You will need to add the directory containing the executable to the system path.

- On Unix systems you can do the following to append it to your system’s search path, if you’re using a Bash-compatible shell:

  ```bash
  export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/directory/of/executable/downloaded/in/previous/step
  ```
- On Windows you will need to update the **Path system variable to add the full directory path to the executable geckodriver** [manually](https://www.google.co.in/amp/www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/amp/?client=ms-android-motorola) or [command line](https://www.windows-commandline.com/set-path-command-line/)** (don't forget to restart your system after adding executable geckodriver into system PATH to take effect)**. The principle is the same as on Unix.

Now you can run your code same as you're doing as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line

The exception clearly states you have installed Firefox some other location while Selenium is trying to find Firefox and launch from the default location, but it couldn't find it. You need to provide explicitly Firefox installed binary location to launch Firefox as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('path/to/installed firefox binary')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

Comment: Thanks but I set the my `geckodriver.exe` on the `C:\Python\Python35\selenium` directory and I set the path like you described but it's giving me the error below:

Comment: `'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line'`

Comment: That means path problem has been resolved, this clearly states you didn't installed firefox in the default location, so you need provide explicitly firefox installed location to launch

Comment: Thanks @Saurabh Gaur, it's working now. I added the path of Firefox to the system variables manually and it's all working. Takes a little bit of time to launch but I'm guessing that's normal. Thanks!

Comment: I had exactly the same issue as the thread starter(the original issue). However simply adding the path of the .exe did not work. The .exe had to be in the python35 folder.

Comment: I got the error "WebDriverException: Message: Failed to start browser: permission denied" at first when I started specifying the firefox binary path, but restarting the computer (Windows 10) resolved the problem. - Just in case anyone else is hitting the same problem as me.

Comment: on osx I put it `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: What is the binary? Does that mean executable?

Comment: In addition to this answer, I would like to expand on setting the `PATH` in unix environment.

You can set it in code since you don't need it system wide: `os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'path/to/dir/containing/geckodriver/'`

Or simply keep the geckodriver binary in the directory that is already in your path: `mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin`

Comment: Where to download `geckodriver` from? The github repo consists of two files only...

Comment: @Alex you can [download latest `geckodriver ` v018.0 from here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.18.0)

Comment: Weirdly, it won't work from /usr/bin even though that folder is in PATH.  Had to put it in my home directory.

Comment: Windows user: Don't forget to **restart** after changing the path. IMO the most important part. I've struggled an hour until I found this answer :-/

Comment: You can get geckodriver in ubuntu 20 using command bellow: sudo apt install firefox-geckodriver

Comment: @ascripter I added it to the path and restarted but I'm still getting the same error as in the OP's question.

Comment: I'm getting `firefox_binary has been deprecated` -warning. I think this answer contains the currently working approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58404246/1548275

Answer (score 225):

This solved it for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'your\path\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('http://inventwithpython.com')
```

Comment: If you get wrong permission try to remove [r'] from the path just "excecutable_path='path\to\your'diretory'"

Comment: @adityarawat what operating system are you on?

Comment: but now i am getting OSError instead of wrong permissions. I somehow managed to copy geckodriver to /usr/local/bin. but now this new error is killing me

Comment: @adityarawat you can download geckodriver independently from here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases extract it with tar and make it executable with chmod +x, it doesn't have to be in /usr/local/bin, you just have to specify your path to it

Comment: just to be clear i have downloaded arm7hf.tar file and extracted it as well and added it to the path using the command  `export PATH=$PATH:geckodriver` (it is extracted in Desktop). But it didn't help either. I still get  OSError[errno 8 ]

Comment: @adityarawat and did you make it executable? If you do it with my method, then you don't have to export the path to it

Comment: guess what. It is now working on idle but not on pycharm(it is completly useless). And even if it did start firefox it did not assert the title i want it to. But i think it solved the problem. Thanks @Nesa. but it still display wrong permissions in pycharm even though i provided all  the permissions.

Comment: It throws `selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities`

Comment: It worked on Cent OS 7. I need to write `executable_path` explicitly as keyword argument. No keyword argument causes an error.

Comment: I am working on Windows using Jupyter Lab. i found this to be the best solution. I copied the geckodriver.exe to my project for convenience. Now I do not even have to add it to PATH or give the directory path explicitly.

Comment: Works, but I did have to put the .exe in a local drive (did not work on a network place)

Comment: It worked for me, I just downloaded the geckodriver from the link and added its path. Thanks bro !!!

Comment: What platform? Windows?

Comment: python 3: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object

Comment: python 3.10, windows, firefox: TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'. This needs a `Service` object, try https://stackoverflow.com/a/76580522

Answer (score 144):

This steps *solved* it for me on Ubuntu and Firefox 50.

1. Download [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
2. Copy geckodriver to folder `/usr/local/bin`

You do *not* need to add:

```
firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
firefox_capabilities['binary'] = '/usr/bin/firefox'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
```

Comment: In your code you can not add the capability variable

Comment: Would you happen to know how to set the download directory for Firefox? I added the following question [Set Firefox Preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644381/python-set-firefox-preferences-for-selenium-download-location). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In Debian or Ubuntu you must use apt command for install Firefox. For Windows I've no idea sorry

Comment: Thanks. After applying this answer, I further took this solution for handling a follow-up issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43713445/selenium-unable-to-find-a-matching-set-of-capabilities-despite-driver-being-in

Comment: Thanks, Pycharm wasn't finding geckodriver although it was in home and in the project folder itself, but after moving it to /usr/local/bin it worked perfectly

Comment: Here is what worked for me : https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-selenium-tools-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 72):

I see the discussions still talk about the old way of setting up geckodriver by downloading the binary and configuring the path manually.

This can be done automatically using [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

Now the above code in the question will work simply with the below change,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: Does Safari or even Internet Explorer have a similar driver manager?

Comment: Or using `pip3`?

Comment: It sort of works, but I think `geckodriver` needs to be in the path. Temporary, like: `export PATH=$PATH:/home/embo/.wdm/drivers/geckodriver/linux64/v0.28.0`

Comment: Awesome! This is so much easier!

Comment: Thanks heaps. This was the only thing that worked. I was running a cron job that spawned a program to a thread that ran selenium.

Comment: Part of the transcript from ***the first run*** of `GeckoDriverManager().install()` is something like *"Trying to download new driver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.30.0/geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz. Driver has been saved in cache [/home/mortensen/.wdm/drivers/geckodriver/linux64/v0.30.0]"*

Comment: This helped thenk you. so cool

Comment: The parameter 'executable_path'  got deprecated in Selenium 4.  To avoid deprecation warning do: webdriver.Firefox(service=webdriver.firefox.service.Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

Answer (score 42):

On macOS with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) already installed, you can simply run the Terminal command:

```
brew install geckodriver
```

Because Homebrew already did extend the `PATH` there isn’t any need to modify any startup scripts.

Comment: @roskakori I did this and it got installed successfully but still I am getting the same error

Comment: This did it for me, thanks. Using Firefox 72.0.2 & Selenium 3.141.0

Comment: This worked for me as well without needing to modify anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 38):

The [answer by saurabh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path/40208762#40208762) solves the issue, but it doesn't explain why *Automate the Boring Stuff with Python* doesn't include those steps.

This is caused by the book being based on Selenium 2.x and the Firefox driver for that series does not need the Gecko driver. The Gecko interface to drive the browser was not available when Selenium was being developed.

The [latest version](https://pypi.python.org/simple/selenium/) in the Selenium 2.x series is 2.53.6 (see e.g. [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40746017/1307905), for an easier view of the versions).

The [2.53.6 version page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium/2.53.6) doesn't mention Gecko at all. But since version 3.0.2 the documentation [explicitly states](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium#drivers) you need to install the Gecko driver.

If after an upgrade (or install on a new system), your software that worked fine before (or on your old system) doesn't work anymore and you are in a hurry, pin the Selenium version in your virtualenv by doing

```
pip install selenium==2.53.6
```

but of course the long term solution for development is to setup a new virtualenv with the latest version of selenium, install the Gecko driver and test if everything still works as expected.

But the major version bump might introduce other API changes that are not covered by your book, so you might want to stick with the older Selenium, until you are confident enough that you can fix any discrepancies between the Selenium 2 and Selenium 3 API yourself.

Answer (score 24):

***To set up geckodriver for Selenium Python:***

It needs to set the geckodriver path with FirefoxDriver as the below code:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'D:\Selenium_RiponAlWasim\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')
```

Download geckodriver for your suitable OS (from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) → Extract it in a folder of your choice → Set the path correctly as mentioned above.

I'm using Python 3.6.2 and Selenium WebDriver 3.4.3 on Windows 10.

***Another way to set up geckodriver:***

i) Simply paste the geckodriver.exe under /Python/Scripts/ (in my case the folder was: `C:\Python36\Scripts`)
ii) Now write the simple code as below:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Answer (score 21):

If you are using [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/), all you have to do is  activate your virtual environment and then install **geckodriver** using the following [command](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/geckodriver):

```
conda install -c conda-forge geckodriver
```

Comment: Yes, it installs geckodriver, but pycharm error stays the same.

Comment: Unlike the other solutions presented above, this one worked perfectly for me under Windows 10. No geckodriver.exe to download, no env variable to set. Simple and easy. Thxs.

Answer (score 21):

#### [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29)+ and the newest release of geckodriver

This should also work for other Unix-like varieties as well.

```bash
export GV=v0.30.0
wget "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/$GV/geckodriver-$GV-linux64.tar.gz"
tar xvzf geckodriver-$GV-linux64.tar.gz
chmod +x geckodriver
sudo cp geckodriver /usr/local/bin/
```

For Mac update to:

```bash
geckodriver-$GV-macos.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 13):

**The easiest way for Windows!**

Download the latest version of `geckodriver` from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). Add the ***geckodriver.exe*** file to the Python directory (or any other directory which already in `PATH`). This should solve the problem (it was tested on Windows 10).

Comment: Windows Server 2019 - after adding path to geckodriver.exe in system it not worked but after copying geckodiriver.exe to python path it works ! Thank You : )

Answer (score 11):

`geckodriver` is not installed by default.

```
geckodriver
```

Output:

```
Command 'geckodriver' not found, but it can be installed with:

sudo apt install firefox-geckodriver
```

The following command not only installs it, but it also puts it in the executable `PATH`.

```
sudo apt install firefox-geckodriver
```

The problem is solved with only a single step. I had exactly the same error as you and it was gone as soon as I installed it. Go ahead and give it a try.

```
which geckodriver
```

Output:

```
/usr/bin/geckodriver
```

---

```
geckodriver
```

Output:

```
1337    geckodriver    INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:4444
^C
```

Comment: This worked for me. Also it removes the pain of downloading the driver and the putting it in proper path.

Comment: This is the actual answer.

Comment: easy and simple

Answer (score 10):

For versions [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) and later you can do:

For Firefox: 
`sudo apt-get install firefox-geckodriver`

For Chrome: 
`sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver`

Comment: Solved my problem for firefox.

Answer (score 9):

### Steps for Mac

The simple solution is to download GeckoDriver and add it to your system PATH. You can use either of the two approaches:

#### Short Method

1. Download and unzip [Geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).
2. Mention the path while initiating the driver:

   ```
   driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/your/path/to/geckodriver')
   ```

#### Long Method

1. Download and unzip [Geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).
2. Open `.bash_profile`. If you haven't created it yet, you can do so using the command: `touch ~/.bash_profile`. Then open it using: `open ~/.bash_profile`
3. Considering GeckoDriver file is present in your Downloads folder, you can add the following line(s) to the `.bash_profile` file:

   ```
   PATH="/Users/<your-name>/Downloads/geckodriver:$PATH"
   export PATH
   ```

By this you are appending the path to GeckoDriver to your System PATH. This tells the system where GeckoDriver is located when executing your Selenium scripts.

4. Save the `.bash_profile` and force it to execute. This loads the values immediately without having to reboot. To do this you can run the following command:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

5. That's it. You are *done*! You can run the Python script now.

Comment: I was able to download `geckodriver` with Homebrew: `brew install geckodriver` and then initiate Firefox via: `driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")`

Answer (score 8):

Some additional input/clarification:

The following suffices as a resolution for Windows 7, Python 3.6, and Selenium 3.11:

[dsalaj's note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path/45739867#comment73032586_40208762) for another answer for Unix is applicable to Windows as well; tinkering with the PATH environment variable at the Windows level and restart of the Windows system can be avoided.

(1) Download geckodriver (as described in this thread earlier) and place the (unzipped) geckdriver.exe at X:\Folder\of\your\choice

(2) Python code sample:

```
import os;
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + r'X:\Folder\of\your\choice';

from selenium import webdriver;
browser = webdriver.Firefox();
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
assert 'Django' in browser.title
```

Notes:

(1) It may take about 10 seconds for the above code to open up the Firefox browser for the specified URL.

(2) The Python console would show the following error if there's no server already running at the specified URL or serving a page with the title containing the string 'Django':

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=connectionFailure&u=http%3A//localhost%3A8000/&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=Firefox%20can%E2%80%9

Answer (score 6):

I've actually discovered you can use the latest geckodriver without putting it in the system path. Currently I'm using

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.12.0/geckodriver-v0.12.0-win64.zip

Firefox 50.1.0

Python 3.5.2

Selenium 3.0.2

Windows 10

I'm running a VirtualEnv (which I manage using [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm), and I assume it uses Pip to install everything).

In the following code I can use a specific path for the geckodriver using the executable_path parameter (I discovered this by having a look in
Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py ). Note I have a suspicion that the order of parameter arguments when calling the webdriver is important, which is why the executable_path is last in my code (the second to last line off to the far right).

You may also notice I use a custom Firefox profile to get around the sec_error_unknown_issuer problem that you will run into if the site you're testing has an untrusted certificate. See *[How to disable Firefox's untrusted connection warning using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879566/how-to-disable-firefoxs-untrusted-connection-warning-using-selenium)*

After investigation it was found that the Marionette driver is incomplete and still in progress, and no amount of setting various capabilities or profile options for dismissing or setting certificates was going to work. So it was just easier to use a custom profile.

Anyway, here's the code on how I got the geckodriver to work without being in the path:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True

#you probably don't need the next 3 lines they don't seem to work anyway
firefox_capabilities['handleAlerts'] = True
firefox_capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True
firefox_capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True

# In the next line I'm using a specific Firefox profile because
# I wanted to get around the sec_error_unknown_issuer problems with the new Firefox and Marionette driver
# I create a Firefox profile where I had already made an exception for the site I'm testing
# see https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles#w_starting-the-profile-manager

ffProfilePath = 'D:\Work\PyTestFramework\FirefoxSeleniumProfile'
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_directory=ffProfilePath)
geckoPath = 'D:\Work\PyTestFramework\geckodriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, capabilities=firefox_capabilities, executable_path=geckoPath)
browser.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
```

Comment: I got SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes... And I have to change gecko path to epath = r'C:\Users\step_\Documents\mtg_buyer\geckodrivers\geckodriver.exe'. Maybe the reason is that I'm using a Chinese Windows 10?

Answer (score 6):

A new way to avert the error is using [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) environments.

Use `conda install -c conda-forge geckodriver` and you do not have to add anything to the path or edit the code!

Comment: I tried this in VSCode, was able to run pytest with webdriver(for Firefox) with Selenium.

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this issue by using a simple command if you are on **Linux**

1. First, download (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and extract the ZIP file
2. Open the extracted folder
3. Open the terminal from the folder (where the `geckodriver` file is located after extraction)

   [image]
4. Now run this simple command on your terminal to copy the geckodriver into the correct folder:

   ```
    sudo cp geckodriver /usr/local/bin
   ```

Answer (score 4):

It's really rather sad that none of the books published on Selenium/Python and most of the comments on this issue via Google do not clearly explain the pathing logic to set this up on Mac (everything is Windows!). The YouTube videos all pickup at the "after" you've got the pathing setup (in my mind, the cheap way out!). So, for you wonderful Mac users, use the following to edit your Bash path files:

```bash
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile*
```

Then add a path something like this....

```bash
# Setting PATH for geckodriver
PATH=“/usr/bin/geckodriver:${PATH}”
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Selenium Firefox
PATH=“~/Users/yourNamePATH/VEnvPythonInterpreter/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/:${PATH}”
export PATH

# Setting PATH for executable on Firefox driver
PATH=“/Users/yournamePATH/VEnvPythonInterpreter/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py:${PATH}”
export PATH*
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Consider installing a containerized Firefox:

```
docker pull selenium/standalone-firefox
docker run --rm -d -p 5555:4444 --shm-size=2g selenium/standalone-firefox
```

Connect using `webdriver.Remote`:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:5555/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
driver.set_window_size(1280, 1024)
driver.get('https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/browserinfo/')
driver.save_screenshot('info.png')
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Windows 10 and this worked for me:

1. Download geckodriver from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). Download the right version for the computer you are using.
2. Unzip the file you just downloaded and cut/copy the ".exe" file it contains
3. Navigate to C:{your python root folder}. Mine was C:\Python27. Paste the geckodriver.exe file in this folder.
4. Restart your development environment.
5. Try running the code again. It should work now.

Answer (score 3):

```
from webdriverdownloader import GeckoDriverDownloader # vs ChromeDriverDownloader vs OperaChromiumDriverDownloader
gdd = GeckoDriverDownloader()
gdd.download_and_install()
#gdd.download_and_install("v0.19.0")
```

This will get you the path to your gekodriver.exe on Windows.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\Users\\username\\\bin\\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/')
```

Answer (score 3):

For *MacBook users*:

Step 1:

Open [this link](https://brew.sh) and copy that [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) path, paste it in terminal and install it.

Step 2:

```
brew install geckodriver
```

Step 3:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

Answer (score 2):

Selenium answers this question in their *DESCRIPTION.rst* file:

> Drivers 
> =======
>
> Selenium requires a driver to interface with the chosen browser. Firefox,
> for example, requires `geckodriver <https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases>`_, which needs to be installed before the below examples can be run. Make sure it's in your `PATH`, e. g., place it in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.

> Failure to observe this step will give you an error `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Basically just download the geckodriver, unpack it and move the executable to your */usr/bin* folder.

Comment: This quote contains the directions that worked on linux mint 18 .

Answer (score 2):

> **For Windows users**

Use the original code as it's:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Then download the driver from: [mozilla/geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Place it in a fixed path (permanently)... As an example, I put it in:

> C:\Python35

Then go to the environment variables of the system. In the grid of "System variables" look for the *Path* variable and add:

> ;C:\Python35\geckodriver

geckodriver, **not geckodriver.exe**.

Comment: geckodriver, not geckodriver.exe.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a virtual environment and Windows 10 (maybe it's the same for other systems), you just need to put geckodriver.exe into the following folder in your virtual environment directory:

...\my_virtual_env_directory\Scripts\geckodriver.exe

Comment: Exactly... installing geckodriver inside the environment's lib(Unix) or Scripts(Windows) directory helps solve this problem while using a virtual environment.

Answer (score 2):

I developed a script on Linux desktop, to deploy on my headless server. I needed to update running on Windows but got this same error for a couple of reasons:

> "selenium.common.exceptions.sessionnotcreatedexception: message: expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxoptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line"

This is Windows; I needed to install Firefox, which I probably goofed up because it was lagging and I had two installations progressing for a time.

Once Firefox was installed I found a confirmed solution (eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/42122284) instructing me to use `executable_path`:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'your\path\geckodriver.exe')
```

That parameter is unrecognised since a couple of years ago. Instead I need a `Service` instance. I add this alongside my options, which were required because Firefox still could not be found (which my impatience double installing might be blamed for):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
opts.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
service = Service(r"C:\Users\pythonista\PycharmProjects\world_eater\geckodriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=opts)
```

This is my only selenium project presently, it can manage its own geckodriver.

Answer (score 1):

On [macOS v10.12.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra) (Sierra) and Python 2.7.10, this works for me:

```
def download(url):
    firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
    firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities,
                                executable_path=r'/Users/Do01/Documents/crawler-env/geckodriver')
    browser.get(url)
    return browser.page_source
```

Answer (score 1):

On Raspberry Pi I had to create it from the ARM driver and set the geckodriver and log path in file *webdriver.py*:

```
sudo nano /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py
```

```
def __init__(self, firefox_profile=None, firefox_binary=None,
             timeout=30, capabilities=None, proxy=None,
             executable_path="/PATH/gecko/geckodriver",
             firefox_options=None,
             log_path="/PATH/geckodriver.log"):
```

Comment: Create what? From [an ARM driver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=17m54s)? From [the ARM driver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=19m05s) (is there more than one)? What is *"ARM driver"*? Can you elaborate?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *Last seen more than 4 years ago*

Answer (score 1):

For me it was enough just to install `geckodriver` in the same environment:

```
brew install geckodriver
```

And the code was not changed:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Answer (score 1):

The major changes of `selenium` `4.10.0` mean that you'll no longer see the Geckodriver error message if you upgrade your `selenium` version. `selenium` has a built-in driver manager (now fully out of beta) that will automatically download `geckodriver` for you if it's not found on your system `PATH`. Even the method arg `executable_path` has been removed from `webdriver.Firefox()`, as seen below:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

[image: Changes_in_selenium_4_10_0]

Now, this is all you need to launch Firefox, even if it is not on your System Path:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# ...
driver.quit()
```

To customize Firefox, use the `options` and `service` args:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

(As before, `geckodriver` will be downloaded automatically if it is not found on your system `PATH`.)

Answer (score 0):

Visit [Gecko Driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and get the URL for the Gecko driver from the *Downloads* section.

Clone this repository: https://github.com/jackton1/script_install.git

`cd script_install`

Run

```
./installer --gecko-driver https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.18.0/geckodriver-v0.25.0-linux64.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 10 and [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) 2. I tried setting the system path variable, but it didn't work out. Then I simply added geckodriver.exe file to the Anaconda 2/Scripts folder and everything works great now.

For me the path was:

```
C:\Users\Bhavya\Anaconda2\Scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the driver paths on Windows 10:

1. Right click on the "This PC" icon and select "Properties"

   [image]
2. Click on “Advanced System Settings”
3. Click on “Environment Variables” at the bottom of the screen
4. In the “User Variables” section highlight “Path” and click “Edit”
5. Add the paths to your variables by clicking “New” and typing in the path for the driver you are adding and hitting enter.
6. Once you done entering in the path, click “OK”
7. Keep clicking “OK” until you have closed out all the screens

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to do `echo PATH` (Linux) and just move `geckodriver` to the folder of your liking. If a system (not virtual environment) folder is the target, the driver becomes globally accessible.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 it works for me downloading the geckodriver.exe. I just had to update Firefox.

Below the code that I used:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path=r'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Automate the boring stuff with python exercises\Web Scraping\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('http://inventwithpython.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

...implies that your program was unable to locate the specified file and while handling the exception the following exception occurred:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

... which implies that your program was unable to locate the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) in the process of initiating/spawnning a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Firefox Browser* session.

---

You can download the latest [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510338/selenium-webdriver-3-4-0-geckodriver-0-18-0-firefox-which-combination-w/45510453#45510453) from [**mozilla / geckodriver**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), unzip/untar and store the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073748/which-firefox-version-is-compatible-with-selenium-3-6-0/47095220#47095220) binary/executable anywhere with in your system passing the absolute path of the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947694/webdriverexception-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path-even-though-it/49955135#49955135) through the *key* `executable_path` as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

---

In case [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) is not installed at the default location (i.e. installed at a custom location) additionally you need to pass the absolute path of `firefox` binary through the attribute `binary_location` as follows:

```
# An Windows example
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Manual steps to install geckodriver on Ubuntu

- Visit https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
- Download the latest version of "geckodriver-vX.XX.X-linux64.tar.gz"
- Unarchive the tarball (tar -xvzf geckodriver-vX.XX.X-linux64.tar.gz)
- Give executable permissions to geckodriver (chmod +x geckodriver)
- Move the geckodriver binary to /usr/local/bin or any location on your system PATH.

**Script to install geckodriver on Ubuntu:**

```
#!/bin/bash

INSTALL_DIR="/usr/local/bin"

json=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest)
url=$(echo "$json" | jq -r '.assets[].browser_download_url | select(contains("linux64"))')
curl -s -L "$url" | tar -xz
chmod +x geckodriver
sudo mv geckodriver "$INSTALL_DIR"
echo "installed geckodriver binary in $INSTALL_DIR"
```

<sub>*This answer was entirely copied from:
[Corey Goldberg's answer to *How to install geckodriver in Ubuntu?*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870530/how-to-install-geckodriver-in-ubuntu)*</sub>